# Microsoft surface 2 with windows 8 rt

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-rt

I am planning to buy Microsoft surface 2 with windows 8 rt, am I able to run JVM on it, will I be able to use Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can install only Windows Store apps on Windows RT devices such as Surface 2.

You can run any Windows app on a Windows 8.1 device such as Surface Pro 2 or Surface Pro 3.